# Weird Laravel Blade rendering with @ escape character

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using `@` escape character so that Blade allow me write some JS template. But I ended up with some unexpected behaviors.

```
@{{ a }} Outputs: {{ a }} 
@{{ {{ a }} }} Outputs: {{ {{ a }} }}
@{{ {{ a }} {{ b }} }} undefined constant b
@{{ @{{ a }} @{{ b }} }} Outputs: {{ @{{ a }} {{ b }} }}
@{{ {{ a }} @{{ b }} }} Outputs: {{ {{ a }} {{ b }} }}
```

By the way I wish there was some kind of directive in Laravel Blade, so that we can put any type of text in that and be sure it'll be intact in the output?

```
@intact

do {{ what }} ever you want!
@if we were not in @intact block,
there would be plenty of exceptions... {{{

@endintact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```php
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

> Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your
>   application. Always use the escaped, double curly brace syntax to
>   prevent XSS attacks when displaying user supplied data.

You may wrap the HTML in the `@verbatim` directive if you are displaying JavaScript variables in a large portion of your template:

```php
@verbatim
    <div class="container">
        Hello, {{ name }}.
    </div>
@endverbatim
```

See 'Displaying Unescaped Data' and 'The @verbatim Directive' sections on the [blade docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade) for more info.

Comment: Thank you Hafez jane gol